# Why isn't an Adapter with cached buttons working as expected in Android?

Tags: android, listview, click

**Edit3: Exchanged the code for a complete runnable test case.**

Edit2: Added some code that updates the number of buttons after five seconds. When this happens the buttons becomes unclickable no matter what layout you use.

Edit1: It seems this is depending on the Layout used for the ListView. I will investigate further.

I want to create the buttons once, i.e. cache them. I can't use the provided convertView and edit it for various reasons (every row will in the end contain a couple of components, all created by another framework).

If I create an Adapter like below, which seems very reasonable and imo should work, only buttons that have been outside the ListView, and are scrolled back in, are clickable.

It seems the button's clickable area isn't set correctly on first display. Can anyone explain why?

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class TestActivity extends Activity
{
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        final ListView listView = new ListView(this);

        final ArrayList<View> cachedButtons = new ArrayList<View>(Arrays.asList(new View[20]));

        listView.setAdapter(new BaseAdapter() {
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
            {
                if (cachedButtons.get(position) == null) {
                    Button b = new Button(parent.getContext());
                    b.setText("Button " + position);
                    b.setClickable(true);
                    cachedButtons.set(position, b);
                }
                return cachedButtons.get(position);
            }

            public int getCount() { return cachedButtons.size(); }
            public Object getItem(int position) { return null; }
            public long getItemId(int position) { return position; }
        });

        // Add a new button after five seconds
        new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
            public void run()
            {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run()
                    {
                        cachedButtons.addAll(Arrays.asList(new View[1])); // Add one more
                        ((BaseAdapter) listView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
                        Toast.makeText(listView.getContext(), "Now you can't press the buttons anymore", 0).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        }, 5000);

        // Doesn't work with these lines
        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
        layout.addView(listView);
        setContentView(layout);

        // Works with this, so no Layout works.
        //setContentView(layout);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tested your code and ALL buttons are clickable. Maybe this isn't all your code? Also an adapter should be used to bind data to the `ListView` and not views.

Comment: Ok, I've done some more testing. If the buttons are changed, I think the bounds, all becomes non-clickable. Some layout managers does this on a more regular basis, some don't.

If you add the code I've added at the bottom in the original post the buttons becomes non-clickable after five seconds in my test case.

Answer (score 2):

I think Android is reusing your views so that is causing you problems .I suggest you use a view holder .It is a static class that holds the view for you.See [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html) tutorial

Comment: Thanks. Good read.
I find it strange that it is reusing my Views without my permission. Especially since I'm not using convertView. I must way that Swing's API is much better in this regard.

Comment: this is because android has a tight memory system, it reuses to be more memory efficient.

Comment: Yeah, but in Swing's model you can use just one View, which is even better.

Comment: in swing you dont have memory constraints but here since its on Mobile you have memory constraints.Even Java core has been modified and its not exactly the same under the hood.

Answer (score 2):

The answer was quite simple, yet eluded me for many hours. Just override getItemViewType and the views won't be recycled. At least it seems to work for now. I still find the JavaDocs confusing on this.

```
public int getItemViewType(int position)
{
    return AdapterView.ITEM_VIEW_TYPE_IGNORE;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, good find. This is probably a satisfactory solution if you can guarantee a small number of items (less than a hundred or so). If anyone knows better please let me know.