# Custom ListView Adapter to change certain items

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

I've written a custom ListView adapter for Android to change the visual aspects of my data. When I load my ListView, the desired items have their appearance changed. When I scroll the view, other items will change at random until eventually every item in the list has had its appearance modified.

From what I've read on SO about this type of code, I know that the `position` field in
`public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)`
does not necessarily map to my data structure, since Android re-uses old views. This seems to be the behavior I'm struggling to work with.

Updated getView method using the ViewHolder pattern as Vincent suggests:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View rowView = convertView;
    if (rowView == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, null);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.text = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tv01);
        rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }

    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
    String s = names[position];
    holder.text.setText(s);
    if (s.startsWith("a"))
    {
        holder.text.setTextColor(0xff00ffff);
    }

    return rowView;
}
```

The items I need to modify are static, so if there is a better approach than changing them at run-time, that would also work! Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Do you have child views in rowView, excepting tv01?

Comment: Please post code of your ViewHolder, so that we can see its member fields.

Answer (score 0):

your layout is being reused by android so that is why you are getting this output.What you need to do is to have a class that will act as a static viewholder for each of your view and use it as tag .See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10162100/1075066)  for reference

Comment: Ugh.. timed out on my edit...  Vincent, thanks, I tried that pattern, and am still having the issue. Updated my post with the new getView

Answer (score 0):

You're not modifying existing views. If convertView is not null that means Android is recycling the view instead of inflating it, but you still have to update it with the new values. Something like this will work:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
ViewHolder holder;          

if(convertView == null) {
    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, null);
    holder = new ViewHolder();  
}
else {
    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
}
holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv01); 
convertView.setTag(holder);

return convertView;
```

}